# Jquery if checked load html

Tags: jquery

Hey All,
Thanks in advance for taking a look at my challenge. I've been wrestling with it for a couple days now and could really use a hand.

**The Situation:**
When the user clicks a checkbox, I would like to populate the "div#partners_internal_products_registration" with the HTML contents specific to that checkbox. If the user decides the would like to made a different selection the new content will replace the existing content in the same

[JS fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P7EKH/17/)

Comment: if you want only one checked, why not use radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var checkboxes = $(':checkbox.productselect');
checkboxes.click(function(){
  checkboxes.attr('checked', false);
  $(this).attr('checked',true);
  $('#selection'+this.id+'content').load('1.html');
  //this is under the assumtion that every checkbox has the id of the content u want to update
})
```

It will 1st set ALL to false, then set the one u want to checked.

**UPDATE**

look above

Comment: Thanks Maniator!
From do you have a suggestion of how to check #selectioncontent, clear contents, then inject HTML?

Comment: "From do you have a suggestion of how to check #selectioncontent, clear contents, then inject HTML?"
If I understand this correctly, you don't need to clear #selectioncontent first and then inject HTML. load() will take care of that, as it replaces whatever was there before.

Comment: Thanks ilia, thats good to know.

I realize that in my attempt to create a mock example with fake classes I might have made it difficult to understand. I've uploaded the working example in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/P7EKH/17/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selection1').change({
       if($(this).test(":checked")) {
             $('#selectioncontent').load('1.html');
       }
       uncheckAll();
});

function uncheckAll() {
    $(':checkbox.productselect').each(fnction() {
        $(this).attr("checked",false);
    });
}
```

this should work

Comment: Thanks for your help, I couldn't get it working. I have a live example running if you want to apply your code to it. Thanks again

http://jsfiddle.net/P7EKH/17/

Comment: what is the problem with the jsfiddle?

Comment: I want to load content into #partners_internal_product_registration when user checks a checkbox. 

Each checkbox should load different content.
Content should always loads into the same div and replace what is currently there.